# SQL Server -- Join Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with following rows :

| SectionId | SectionStatus |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Assigned |
| 1 | Approved |
| 2 | Assigned |
| 2 | Assigned |
| 3 | Assigned |

Now I want to fetch the SectionId where al SectionStatus belong to that SectionId are not Approved.

Result expected for above table  : 1,2,3

Another Example :

| SectionId | SectionStatus |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Approved |
| 1 | Approved |
| 2 | Assigned |
| 2 | Assigned |
| 3 | Assigned |

Result expected for above table :  2,3

Answer (score 1):

This looks like aggregation with a conditional count in the `HAVING` clause.

```sql
SELECT t.SectionId
FROM yourtable t
GROUP BY t.SectionId
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN t.SectionStatus = 'Approved' THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=685b4fb4c1e87c503d898a4046f66244)

Answer (score 0):

One way to get that is by cross-applying the record and check whether that is 'Approved' or not.

Try the following:

```
select distinct SectionId from yourtable tab
cross apply (select 'Approved' Stat)t 
where t.Stat <> tab.SectionStatus
```

Please see the db<>fiddle **[here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=37cdee82336b53db5bdf249d1369aef2)**.